# limits for positive and negative infinity

Tags: infinity

[image]
It says we use the l'hospital's rule, however I don't understand because the limit for positive infinity and negative infinity are different. Please help!

Comment: Why should the limits for positive and negative infinity be the same?  What are the two limits for $x$?  for $\mathrm{e}^x$?  for $\tan^{-1}x$? ...

Comment: the asymptotes are -1 and 5  E

Comment: You should not use L'Hospital's Rule for the limit as  $x\to-\infty$. For the limit as $x\to\infty$, you can, but it is not the best way.

Comment: How do we end up with the answer of -1 and 5?

Comment: As $x\to-\infty$, the $2^x$ parts die. As $x\to\infty$, the $2^x$ parts take over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we find
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{5+2^x}{1-2^x}.$$
But $2^x\to 0$ as $x\to-\infty$,  and therefore the required limit is $\frac{5}{1}$.

Next we find
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5+2^x}{1-2^x}.$$
Divide top and bottom by $2^x$. So we want
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5\cdot 2^{-x}+1}{e^{-x}-1}.$$
But $2^{-x}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, and therefore the required limit is $\frac{1}{-1}$.

**Remark:** For the limit as $x\to -\infty$, we cannot use L'Hospital's Rule directly, since top and bottom both have finite limits. We *could* after some manipulation rewrite things so that L'Hospital's Rule can be used, but it is harder than the direct approach we took.

For the limit as $x\to\infty$, we can use L'Hospital's Rule. Recall that the derivative of $2^x$ is $(\ln 2)2^x$. L'Hospital's Rule then gives
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5+2^x}{1-2^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\ln 2)2^x}{-(\ln 2)2^x}.$$
Cancellation now gives that the limit is $-1$. I much prefer the approach of the main answer above.